# Database Archive Through Java/Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, db2, archive

I am new to stackOverflow, I have requirements where I have 76 tables which needs to be Archived to another Database which has same table structure for all 76 tables. Some tables are can be archived based on some business conditions. We are using DB2 Database and  Hibernate for DAO layer. I need help in designing the Archive process. I want to have that process as Table Driven. I analyzed below strategies

1) Use DB2 Export to export the data to flat file and load the data to Archive DB. But, in this way, i cannot use it with table driven and have some difficulty when considering business logics.

2) Use DB links to connect to Archive DB, select data from main table and load them into Archive DB using DB link. But, I don't know how hibernate support the DB link.

3) I thought of create two different Hibernate SessionFactory for main DB and Archive DB. And, retreive the data using HQL or Criteria and save it to Archive DB. But in this way, I may need to hold session from both the DB for long which may cause some table locking issue.

Please suggest me any better solutions. Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "table driven process"?

Comment: Why do you want to use Hibernate for a batch process? this could increase the network usage, and the CPU process is much more.

Comment: Table Driven means, i have table where i need to keep the table and how many records have been moved and purged. And, also, i want to note how much time it is taking. If I want to add another table, to my Archive process, i can add entry, so it can pickup new table to Archive.

Comment: If the tables are not too huge, you could use JDBC to read a table from one connection and insert it into an  identical table on a different connection.